# Is a non-WAAS Garmin 530 certified for an LNAV/VNAV approach?

Tags: avionics, approach, gnss

I may not understand all the details of what I'm asking but trying to wrap my head around it.

I am aware that before WAAS, some GPS aircraft were equipped to get vertical guidance by a Barocorrected altitude information sent to the FMS and along with the non-waas GPS could calculate (interpolate) glide path info and were approved to fly LNAV/VNAV approaches.

My question is whether the non-waas Garmin 530 has the ability and necessary FAA approval to perform this and if it is an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems if used on its own, the 5xx is not capable of LNAV/VNAV approaches.

[image]

Source: [garmin.com](https://fly.garmin.com/fly-garmin/support/icao-flight-plans) — scroll down to the link that reads: <s>"Garmin Flight Plan Information Excel file".</s>

The Excel file was taken down; the page now refers to a Garmin app. For informational purposes only, that Excel file is available [via Web Archive via sportys.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20210520194229/https://dl.videos.sportys.com/assets/IPN/Garmin_ICAO_Flight_Plan.xlsx) (thanks @user2070305).